# extract channel names from a multi-channel image

Tags: python, tiff, scikit-image, imread

I am using `skimage.io.imread` (which uses `tifffile`) to read a QPTIFF file. Multiple channels are successfully read as multiple dimensions. Is it possible to extract the channel names and other metadata?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PerkinElmer QPI metadata are stored as XML in the ImageDescription TIFF tags. To read the XML metadata, use the tifffile.TiffFile class, e.g.:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from tifffile import TiffFile

with TiffFile('LuCa-7color_Scan1.tiff') as tif:
    for page in tif.series[0].pages:
        print(ElementTree.fromstring(page.description).find('Name').text)
```

Comment: If I have to use TiffFile to get the metadata, should I just use `tif.asarray()` instead of `imread` to avoid importing the image twice?

Comment: Yes, use `tif.asarray()` to avoid opening/parsing the TIFF file twice.

Comment: Maybe this is platform specific, but do you know why there are more pages than channels? I see the right number of pages with full-size images, but there are also some subsets.

Comment: Do you mean `tif.pages` or `tif.series[0].pages`? In the first case, there are also pages containing thumbnail, macro, label, and sub-resolution images. As for the second case, I don't have any example where the number of pages does not match the number of channels. Maybe you could share a file?

Comment: Good point. I didn't notice there are both `tif.pages` and `tif.series[0].pages` with very similar contents. If I check `tif.series[0].pages` as you suggested, there are only full size images.